# How to Bundle google cloud endpoint message class in android

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-eclipse-plugin

To pass data from an Activity to a Fragment, naturally, I think of using a `Bundle`. The problem in my case is that the Object I need to pass is a Google Cloud Endpoint message, which is neither Parcelable nor Serializable. So how might I pass the data?

For clarity, a Google Cloud Endpoint message is a POJO that is used to pass data to and from endpoint methods. I assume they would be Serializable, but to my surprise they aren't.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Subclass and implement Serializable or Parcelable on that class
- Or use any other strategy to pass data inside of the app:

  - Singleton class holding any memory cache you may use
  - If the fragment is inside of the activity you can access the fragment from the activity and pass the variable in
  - In the worst of cases you can always use SharedPreferences or any kind of disk persistence